# PyQt5 - How to change PluginsPath with QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath

Tags: pyqt5

Is it possible to modify the PluginsPath via [QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibraryinfo.html#LibraryLocation-enum)?

I want to know if we are forced to use qt.conf.

I use Python3.4 with PyQt5 and I build my script with py2exe.

Comment: [QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath)?

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted!